# Hiding a sub view after selecting a UITableView Row

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitableview

I have a tableview inside a view control on a registration screen. When a row is selected in the table, I want to simply close the view that contains the tableview. Something like this:

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    registrationScreen = new RegistrationScreen();
    registrationScreen.subView.Hidden = true;
}
```

I am not sure that I am supposed to be creating a new instance of the registration screen, because the subview is null after I do that and of course it doesn't work. I think I am missing something really simple, but I am at a loss on how to accomplish. Any help on what I am missing?

Comment: if they select a row you want to close the parent view?  What is going to be displayed instead?  You need a reference to the instance of your parent controller, creating a new one won't help.  You probably need to pass in a reference to the "parent" when you create the TableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a lot of problems with encapsulation myself on iOS. I'm always fighting stuff like, how do I access this class from over here inside this one?

A simple way is to pass in the `RegistrationScreen` to your `UITableViewSource`:

```
private class YourDataSource : UITableViewSource {

    RegistrationScreen screen;

    public YourDataSource(RegistrationScreen screen) {
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    //rest of class
}
```

Pass in the instance of your `RegistrationScreen`, then you can access `screen` in your `RowSelected`.

Is this on the right track with your question?